# RadioButtonList selected value with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I use a form in asp.net (c#) to get some data. In the form  i have some radiobuttonlists.
How can i send to a page the data when already exists a register. 
I ask to the database, if there is a value, radiobuttonlist is selected

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(uno.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

The problem is when i send the data again, just need to update, but the data don't change, are the same that i recovered from the db.

Comment: Show us more code... When / how are you populating the radiobuttonlist? Sounds like you're not databinding after post back.

Comment: Sorry, data changes (i checked on db) but when i refresh de page, the page dont refresh the control RadioButtonList.

Comment: Like I said you need to post more code!

Comment: Thank you very much, i have solved the problem. I did not iterate the items, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % sure on what you are asking, so i'm going to summarize the question I think you are asking and give you the answer.  You are asking how to grammatically select a radio button if you only know the value of the button.

```
radioButtonList1.Items.FindByText("Your Text").Selected = true;

radioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue("Your Text").Selected = true;
```

This will depend if you are searching for the "Value" field or the "Text" Field.  If this is not working then the Value in the radio button and the value in your database are not matching.  Try printing them both off on a screen to see if they are different.

Also Remember that the value and the text are two different properties in the radio button list.

The other question that I think you might be asking is if the page is not being updated at all, in which case did you enable AutoPostBack on the control you are using to implement these changes?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Data changes (i checked on db) but when i refresh de page, the page dont refresh the control RadioButtonList

Comment: I really need to see more code to be able to help you.  Also, are you calling for the update to happen in page load?  If you are not, this will not work.  The page load method is what happens on the website when the page is loaded.  So if you have a method that calls for this you can call that method in the page load, if you are calling for just 1 line of code to make this change then put that line of code in page load and try again.